# Сформировать запрос к серверу через PHP [closed]

Tags: php, linux, веб-программирование, bash, curl

Есть следующий код, который выполняется непосредственно на сервере и успешно отрабатывает. `curl -XPOST -d 'method1=objects.get&arg1={"account_id_abonents":"<ID-абонента>"}&fields=["balance"]' http://<ip:8080/api/v2/Accounts/ -D -`

Возможно ли сформировать такой вопрос через php с удаленного сервера? Если да, то как?

Comment: 1. вомзожно. 2. вот точно так же и напишите, подставив нужные вам ip и порт.

Comment: Через php скрипт это делается?
Эта команда выполняется с консоли сервера. Нужно с удаленного веб сервера. Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+shell_exec+is%3Aa